# Location of a referenced object in an array?

Tags: c#

Background:::::
I am working with a massive (2-dimensional) array of a custom neuron type for a Neural Network that seems to work well. When working with the smaller Neuron array sizes e.g.
Neuron[,] NodeList = new Neuron[800,600];
it will serialize fine.

However it gets stuck in some object tree flattening loop(According to some forum in my history) here and runs out of memory
Neuron[,] NodeList = new Neuron[10000,9000]
After a little research on the Google I found that I will have to use another serializer or implement my own way of saving the data.
I opted for a simple data writer as it would be easier

Problem(Skip here if you want :p):::
For my custom data writer i'm writing all the data needed to a file.
In my Neuron type it stores a reference to another Neuron.
All Neurons stored are all in the NodeList array as mentioned (including linked ones)

```
class Neuron
{
    //Some Old Neuron Info
    float IThreshold = 1;
    float IFiringValue = 1;

    //Link
    float IWeight = 1;
    Neuron NextNeuron;   //This Line HERE
    ...
}
```

For my data writer I am going through each neuron in the array and storing its info... like location in the array, weighting etc
I also want to store the location where its linked neuron is in the array

I would like to do something like

```
int NewX = NodeList[x,y].NextNeuron.ParentArrayIndex(0);
int NewX = NodeList[x,y].NextNeuron.ParentArrayIndex(1);
```

Where the 0 & 1 merely represent the array dimension
Is any of this possible or have a different way of getting it without searching through and checking they equal?

Any help appreciated,... and thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

You are going to need to introduce some sort of persistent identifier for your nodes, for instance:

```
struct NeuronId
{
    ushort Idx0 { get; }
    ushort Idx1 { get; }
}
```

You are also going to need to remember this inside your `Neuron` class.  Having done this, you can have utilities like:

```
NeuronTable.GetNeuron(NeuronId id);

NeuronTable.SetNeuron(Neuron neuron, NeuronId id);
```

The option of keeping a back-reference dictionary `Dictionary<Neuron, NeuronId>` is unlikely to work in your case, since internally the [c# dictionary](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/dictionary.cs)  stores its keys & values in a single dynamic 1-d array of `Entry` structures -- which will likely grow so large as to run out of memory or have more than `Int32.MaxInt` entries!

(I suspect that, when you were serializing your data with the old serializer, it actually cloned the `NextNeuron` nodes.  Microsoft's XML serializer does not automatically convert cross-references to persistent indirect handles.)

Having done that, since you are defining the file format yourself rather than using a standard XML writer, you could write your data in two document sections:

1. The Neuron database.  This serializes the 2d array of neurons including all data *except for the NextNeuron connections*.
2. The cross-reference database.  This serializes all the neurons cross-references as a `KeyValuePair<NeuronId, NeuronId>` list, that you stream out by indexing through the neuron table.

Then on deserialization:

1. Read the nodes into the huge table.
2. Stream in the list of pairs and set up the cross-references.

By the way, is your array sparse?  If so, you might consider using some sort of sparse matrix representation.

Also, if only a tiny, tiny percent of neurons have a non-null NextNeuron, you could avoid storing the NeuronId inside each Neuron and instead build up a `Dictionary<Neuron, NeuronId>` of just the cross-referenced neurons to use while writing.